# Parse error when installing an apk which was downloaded with Chrome, but works just fine when downloaded with Firefox

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, firefox, apk

I'm downloading an apk from a remote server, when i download it via firefox it will install and run. When i download the apk with Chrome, i get the following message in my adb logcat:

```
D TelemetryService: event FunctionalEvent not sent because of consent:NONE , event gdpr level:FUNCTIONAL , event client id:91452636138522988

D         : Zip: EOCD not found, /data/user_de/0/com.android.packageinstaller/cache/package1805045880.apk is not zip
W zipro   : Error opening archive /data/user_de/0/com.android.packageinstaller/cache/package1805045880.apk: Invalid file
D asset   : failed to open Zip archive '/data/user_de/0/com.android.packageinstaller/cache/package1805045880.apk'
W PackageInstaller: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation
```

I can also install the app by using USB. This indicates that the apk itself is not corrupt. I'm wondering why it doesnt work via Chrome?

p.s. Using android devices 7 or higher.

Comment: Could it be caused by the fact that the apk is unsigned? why would it then work in FF and not in chrome?

Comment: it has nothing to do with signing, perhaps chrome is corrupting the APK somehow? Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out, apparantly firefox will download the file and interpret it as a zip whereas other browsers will interpret the package as content.

Take a close look at the 'content-length' attribute in the network tab (in chrome vs firefox debugger) and you might see it is different. The content length of the file that was received by chrome had half the length of the chrome download. Which was odd because both apk files displayed as the same size in kilobytes.

Our developer is currently looking into serving the file a different way through a wildfly server

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I'm having the same problem and would LOVE to know how your developer solved it. This issue ONLY happens for me with Android Chrome - no other browser seems to do this.

Comment: @Dwebtron Hey Dwebtron i am sorry for the late response. I am not sure how he did it as it was quite complex, but i suppose he changed the way that the file was served. because somehow the server seemed to make some sort of estimation of the bytelength of the file, it would just cut off at some wrong point. So maybe try setting this length to infinity or something. If you want i can ask him but it is probably too late now